# android project build on Linux but not on windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-native-library, android-make

I am trying to build [this repository](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android) that contain native codes. it build on Ubuntu without any problem but on windows build was failed showing this error:

```
'make' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I solved this by installing make for windows and added it to path.
but another error appeared:

```
'uname' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**whole of error is:**

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a libwg-quick.so libwg.so}
ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
[1/15] Building wireguard-go
FAILED: CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so 
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\tools\libwg-go && make ANDROID_ARCH_NAME=arm ANDROID_C_COMPILER=C:/Users/hadi/Dev/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT=C:/Users/hadi/Dev/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 ANDROID_SYSROOT= ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME=com.wireguard.android.debug "CFLAGS=-g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wno-unused-command-line-argument" "LDFLAGS=-Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments  -fuse-ld=gold" DESTDIR=C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a BUILDDIR=C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a/../generated-src"
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
mkdir -p "C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a/../generated-src/go-1.13.7/"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -m, ...) failed.
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.
Error occurred while processing: -p.
A subdirectory or file C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a/../generated-src/go-1.13.7/ already exists.
Error occurred while processing: C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a/../generated-src/go-1.13.7/.
make: *** [C:\Users\hadi\Dev\Android\projects\wireguard-android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a/../generated-src/go-1.13.7/.prepared] Error 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

also LLDB, Cmake and NDK installed in sdk manager and in my local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\hadi\\Dev\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\21.0.6113669
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\hadi\\Dev\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: Have you got any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Md.IkramulMurad no! I don't use Windows anymore.
but I had the same problem in another project on Windows and I just copy .so files from the released apk file to jnilibs folder of my project and no need to compile the library as a dependency.

Comment: how were you invoking make? your generated buildsystem seems to be ninja. Seems like a weird thing to do.